# Data label is getting hidden in pie(simple donut) chart.Not adjusting with-in the given space

Tags: javascript, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I am trying to fit in the dynamic text on to the pie chart (donut) with fixed width and height. The data labels with connector are not getting aligned within the specified boundaries which are 550w x 208h. The number of data labels are fixed to be 4.

**I have tried the following:**

1. Increase/decrease distance of connector.
2. Increase/decrease connector-padding.
3. Increase/decrease the radius of the chart.(Wont fit for all the texts).
4. I have tried to use css in the formatter of the function which uses html with word-wrap. Have specified the width in plot options as well.

[image]

The second data label is getting cut.

Comment: Can you show us your code first?

Comment: Could you prepare an online example of your chart?